# Retrieving a Json array from the URL by making a request using jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cs374-csv/country_capital_pairs.csv',
    type :"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(response){
        if(response.success){
            var window = response.pairs;
        }
        else{
            alert("Errors");
        }
    }
});
```

I'm trying to retrieve a Json array from the URL by making a request using jQuery.ajax. My output is displayed like this:

```
window.pairs
(171) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
```

But, the expect output should be like the photo here,
[Expect Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGDiz.png). How can I fix it?

Comment: Where are you displaying it (console, on a website)? What is the format of the JSON you are expecting to receive?

Comment: it will be displayed on console like the photo that I attached in the post.

Comment: Can you please elaborate whats your expected output and what you have currently getting? give sample output details

Comment: Please see the Expect Output link in my post. My current output is like [{...},{...}]